# ASCII art won' t show and stay open

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

why cmd code won't stay on after I try to open the files to keep close quickly

```
@echo off
color a
cls
echo |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                         _                                                                |
echo |                        (_)                                                               |
echo |       _ __ ___    __ _  _  _ __    _ __ ___    ___  _ __   _   _                         |
echo |      | '_ ` _ \  / _` || || '_ \  | '_ ` _ \  / _ \| '_ \ | | | |                        |
echo |      | | | | | || (_| || || | | | | | | | | ||  __/| | | || |_| |                        |
echo |      |_| |_| |_| \__,_||_||_| |_| |_| |_| |_| \___||_| |_| \__,_|                        |
echo |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|                                                                                           |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |                                                                                          |
echo |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
echo Tast
echo !test if work !
pause>nul
```

Comment: How are you running the batch file, by double clicking on it, or from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely due to characters in your ASCII art that need to be escaped so cmd interprets them as a string instead of literally. You can see all characters that need to be escaped [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

The main character you need to escape is the pipe character "|". As seen on the linked page, it needs to be replaced with "^|".

Here's your code with "|" replaced with "^|". It runs as expected on my system.

```
@echo off
color a
cls
echo ^|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                         _                                                                ^|
echo ^|                        (_)                                                               ^|
echo ^|       _ __ ___    __ _  _  _ __    _ __ ___    ___  _ __   _   _                         ^|
echo ^|      ^| '_ ` _ \  / _` ^|^| ^|^| '_ \  ^| '_ ` _ \  / _ \^| '_ \ ^| ^| ^| ^|                        ^|
echo ^|      ^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^|^| (_^| ^|^| ^|^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^| ^|^|  __/^| ^| ^| ^|^| ^|_^| ^|                        ^|
echo ^|      ^|_^| ^|_^| ^|_^| \__,_^|^|_^|^|_^| ^|_^| ^|_^| ^|_^| ^|_^| \___^|^|_^| ^|_^| \__,_^|                        ^|
echo ^|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^|                                                                                           ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|                                                                                          ^|
echo ^|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^|
echo Tast
echo !test if work !
pause>nul
```